# Need some inspiration on how to generate and stream images efficiently on Azure with C#

Tags: c#, image, azure, cdn

I have a situation where I need to display an image to an end user following the below method.

When the user request the image from a URL, the C# code behind should start by looking in an azure blob/cdn to see if the image is there. If the image is there and less than x days old, it should pass the image to the end user in the most efficient way (preferably without spending too many resources (memory & cpu) passing it to the user.

If the image is not there or more than a week old, the image will be generated based on the parameters supplied in the url the user requested, after which it is stored on the blob/cdn and displayed to the end user.

My problem is how, I in the most efficient way on azure, can generate a lot of images simultaneously as well as being able to pass the data from the cdn while still being able to first check if it is too "old" and needs to be regenerated or if it isn't there and needs to be generated before being displayed to the user. Since the second I pass the image through the c# code will loose the cdn's strengths.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do things on azure. You will need to look through the [extensive azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/) and determine what will best fit your needs.

If you want to get something working quickly azure blobs can be served directly to a client (straight to their browser) - [see the doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources) keep in mind anonymous access is not secure.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I just worry that when I get hit with 1000+ requests for images and need to generate them in quickly, it will not work. Problem is, I got no idea on how to address that issue. I thought about web jobs, but they still ramp up very slowly compared to what people would image when requesting a image.

Comment: I would think about whether you really need to solve that case. Azure functions scale fairly well, but you are paying per operation. https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/azure-functions-significant-improvements-in-http-trigger-scaling/

Obviously for the items in the cache compute scaling probably won't be an issue.

Comment: Haven't tried functions yet. Only worked with webjobs, but will take a look. Curious to see if they allow access to graphic transformations :)